# React-native : Stop an automatic refetch when screen is unmounted

Tags: react-native, react-query

I am using React-native and React-query and I want stop the automatic refetch when the screen is unmounted.

Currently, when I go to my target screen, I call a query with an interval parameter :

```
const { data: mission } = useMissionFetcher(missionSelectedId, 5000)
```

useMissionFetcher :

```
export const useMissionFetcher = (idMission: string, interval: number): QueryResult<MissionMobile> => {
    const missionsQueryFn = () => getMission(idMission)
        return useQuery([QueryKeys.mission, idMission], missionsQueryFn, {
          ...baseReactQueryConfig,
          refetchInterval: interval,
        })
  }
```

baseReactQueryConfig :

```
export const baseReactQueryConfig = {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    staleTime: Infinity,
```

How can I do to stop this refetch when I quit the screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you use navigate to get out of your current screen , and that does not unMount the screen it.
Use **navigation.replace** and your react query refetch will automatically stop , since it will be garbaged ( or unMount if you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

Managing focus refetching is different in react-native. The prop `refetchOnWindowFocus` is dependent on `window` which is web only.

What you are looking for is [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#app-states) - this is how React Native manages the `active`/`inactive` states of the screens.

So you can change the behavior of how react-query refetches by working on these events. Reference here: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/window-focus-refetching#managing-focus-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

In case u want to refetch only when you focus your screen because a lot of people want to do this
I think u can juste use this hook

```
export const useRefetchOnFocus = (refetch = () => {}, canRefetch = true) => {
  const [isScreenFocused, setIsScreenFocused] = useState(false);
  useFocusEffect(() => {
    setIsScreenFocused(true); // when i focus the screen
    return () => setIsScreenFocused(false); // when i quit the screen
  });

  /* the screen still always active in cache so we need to check that the screen is focused in a use effect
  to dispatch the refetch only one time to avoid the infinity loop*/
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isScreenFocused && canRefetch) {
      refetch();
    }
  }, [canRefetch, isScreenFocused, refetch]);
};
```

and in your screen

```
  const { data, refetch } = useAccount();

  useRefetchOnFocus(refetch);
```